# CSS: Div position:relative alignment problem

Tags: html, css

I have a problem about div position relative alignment.

I want the second div to be fixed in position even if I remove the first div.
The problem is that the second div adjusts its position when the first div is removed.

My question is how can I retain the position of the second div even if I remove the first div? Thanks :)

This code:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;width:400px;height:150px;margin:0px auto;" >

    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: relative;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 20px; left: 20px;">div-1</div> 

    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: relative;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 60px; left: 20px;">div-2</div>
</div>
```

Will output:

[image]

Then if the first div is removed, the second div adjusts its position.
This code:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;width:400px;height:150px;margin:0px auto;" >

    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: relative;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 60px; left: 20px;">div-2</div>
</div>
```

Will output:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you set the positioning of the outer element to relative, then absolute positioned elements inside of it will be positioned relative to the enclosing one:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;width:400px;height:150px;margin:0px auto; position:relative" >
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: absolute;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 20px; left: 20px;">div-1</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: absolute;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 60px; left: 20px;">div-2</div>
</div>
```

Now you can remove div1 and div2 won't move.

Answer (score 1):

use absolute positioning, which will make the inner div's position absolute to the parent div (aka containing block).

And I would recommend not using inline styles and use a stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #top 
    {
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width:400px;
        height:150px;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    #child1, #child2
    {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 262px;
        height: 20px;
        left: 20px;
    }

    #child1 
    { top: 20px; }
    #child2
    { top: 60px; }
</style>    

 <div id="top">
    <div id="child1">div-1</div>
    <div id="child2">div-2</div>
</div>
```

http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/understanding-css-positioning-part-1/

Comment: @Chad: I used inline style mainly for testing purposes. Thanks by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use absolute positioning - position:absolute or display:none (css).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [visibility CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp) on DIV1 to hidden, and even while being invisible it will take up it's original amount of space on the page.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;width:400px;height:150px;margin:0px auto;" >
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: relative;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 20px; left: 20px;
    visibility:hidden;">div-1</div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; position: relative;
    width: 262px; height: 20px; top: 60px; left: 20px;">div-2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @great_llama: I can't set it to hidden because the div is dynamic AJAX call :)